# Writing out to a gives no new file, but no error either

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, argparse, sys

The goal:

1. take an argument in argparse,
2. test if that argument is true
3. if true, write a file with the name specified after that argument

Eg:
 in the command line:

> $ python printfile.py --out_arg  fileOutput.txt

... would produce a fileOutput.txt in the same directory as printfile.py

Code:

```
def parse_arguments():
    options = parse_arguments()
    #output arguments
    parser.add_argument("--out_arg", action='store', default=False, dest='out_arg',  
     help="""Output file """)

def print_output(seqID, seq, comm):
    # "a" append is used since this is the output of a for loop generator
    if options.out_arg
        outputfh = open(options.out_33,"a")
        outputfh.write("@{}\n{}\n{}\n+".format(seqID, seq, comm))
    else:
        sys.stderr.write("ERR: sys.stdin is without sequence data")
```

Yet, when I call print_output from def main() -not shown- passing in my tuple of interest (seqID, seq, comm), no file is written, and no error message given.  Is it the argparse arguments not storing the inputed file as the dest?  Is it the use of a file handle when trying write?

Comment: What is `options.out_33` here?

Comment: And is `print_output` actually *called*?

Comment: is anything actually called?

Comment: First line of 'def parse_arguments()' is  'options = parse_arguments()'. Are you going in infinite recursion??

Comment: @MartijnPieters options refers to my arguments, and the out_33 is my name for that specific argument.  In this case, `--out_33 < filename >` would be called in the command line to mean, "send this file out in --out_33 format, written to the new file <filename>"  Is options.out_33 no adequately referencing the filename passed in the command line after that argument?

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes, sorry, there is a main function where I call `print_output(seqID, seq, comm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call `close` on the output file. Python's writing is buffered to some degree, and as per the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) if you don't call `flush` or `close` you're not guaranteed to have all the output in the file (or a file at all for short ones).

You should *always* do file IO using the `with open() as ofile:`  syntax to ensure the file is properly flushed/closed:

```
if options.out_arg:
    with open(options.out_33, 'a') as outputfh:
        outputfh.write(...)
else:
    ...
```

Of course, all of this assumes you're actually *calling* `print_output` somewhere, which your code doesn't show. And that `options.out_33` is a relative path and not an absolute one, otherwise the file won't wind up where you expect it to.